# Flutter : How to do this kind of UI in Flutter to select dates

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

Hello Friends,

Can someone guide me to do this kind of UI making in flutter?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this code will work for you. You just need to add your datepicker logic on this textfield.

```
  body: Container(
      child: Row(
    children: [
      Container(
        width: 5,
      ),
      Expanded(
          child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text("Start Date"),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              selectDate(context);
            },
            child: AbsorbPointer(
              absorbing: true,
              child: TextFormField(
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                controller: startdata,
                decoration: InputDecoration(

                    suffixIcon:
                        Icon(Icons.calendar_today, color: Colors.blue)),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      )),
      Container(
        width: 5,
      ),
      Expanded(
          child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text("End Date"),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              // Your second date picker logic
            },
            child: AbsorbPointer(
              absorbing: true,
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: enddata,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    suffixIcon:
                        Icon(Icons.calendar_today, color: Colors.blue)),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      )),
      Container(
        width: 5,
      ),
    ],
  )),
```

Select Date

```
        TextEditingController startdata = new TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController enddata = new TextEditingController();
    DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();
    var myFormat = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
    Future selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
      final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectedDate,
        firstDate: selectedDate,
        lastDate: DateTime(2101),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
          return Theme(
            data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
              primaryColor: WidgetColors.buttonColor,
              accentColor: WidgetColors.buttonColor,
              colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(primary: WidgetColors.buttonColor),
              buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary),
            ),
            child: child,
          );
        },
      );
      if (picked != null) {
        setState(() {
          selectedDate = picked;
          startdata = TextEditingController(text: myFormat.format(picked),);
        });
      } else {}
    }
```

Comment: How can I get the click of the text box and open a date picker

Comment: @Vljay please again check answer =, Now you just need to create for end date

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text("Start Date", style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
            ),),
            SizedBox(height: 15.0,),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                // Show You Date Picker Here
              },
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border(
                    bottom: BorderSide(),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text("YourDate e.g May 7, 2018"),
                    Icon(Icons.calendar_today, color: Colors.blue,),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(width: 10.0,),
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text("End Date", style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
            ),),
            SizedBox(height: 15.0,),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                // Show You Date Picker Here
              },
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border(
                    bottom: BorderSide(),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text("YourDate e.g May 8, 2018"),
                    Icon(Icons.calendar_today, color: Colors.blue,),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  )
```

Comment: How can I get the click of the text box and open a date picker

Comment: @Vljay to do so, first use this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_rounded_date_picker and in the `GestureDetector` call the method `showRoundedDatePicker` of the package

Answer (score 0):

I have a generic `TextFieldWidget` class I use for all my Flutter projects, which is really useful and can answer your question.

```
enum TextFieldType {
  Password,
  Email,
  Text,
  Picker,
}

class TextFieldWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final FocusNode focusNode;
  final Key key;
  final String errorText;
  final String hintText;
  final Color errorBorderColor;
  final bool autofocus;
  final bool isEnabled;
  final Function onChanged;
  final Function onTap;
  final TextFieldType textFieldType;
  final TextCapitalization textCapitalization;
  final Widget suffixIcon;

  TextFieldWidget({
    this.controller,
    this.focusNode,
    this.key,
    this.errorText,
    this.hintText,
    this.errorBorderColor,
    this.autofocus = false,
    this.isEnabled = true,
    this.onChanged,
    this.onTap,
    this.textFieldType = TextFieldType.Text,
    this.textCapitalization = TextCapitalization.none,
    this.suffixIcon,
  });

  @override
  State createState() => _TextFieldWidgetState();
}

class _TextFieldWidgetState extends State<TextFieldWidget> {
  final double _borderSideWidth = 0.5;
  bool _shouldObscureText = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      style: TextStyle(
        color: !widget.isEnabled ? ThemeColors.text.tertiaryLight : null,
        fontSize: ThemeFonts.size.textFieldText,
      ),
      enabled: widget.isEnabled,
      controller: this.widget.controller,
      focusNode: this.widget.focusNode,
      decoration: _getTextFieldDecoration(),
      autofocus: this.widget.autofocus,
      obscureText: _shouldTextBeObscured(),
      onChanged: this.widget.onChanged,
      onTap: this.widget.onTap,
      keyboardType: _getKeyboardType(),
      textCapitalization: this.widget.textCapitalization,
      enableInteractiveSelection: this.widget.textFieldType != TextFieldType.Picker,
    );
  }

  InputDecoration _getTextFieldDecoration() {
    return InputDecoration(
      suffixIcon: _getSuffixIcon(),
      labelText: widget.hintText,
      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: ThemeColors.text.tertiary),
      errorText: widget.errorText,
      errorStyle: TextStyle(
        color: widget.isEnabled ? ThemeColors.text.tertiary : ThemeColors.text.tertiaryLight,
        fontSize: ThemeFonts.size.textFieldPlaceholder,
      ),
      enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: ThemeColors.text.tertiary,
          width: _borderSideWidth,
        ),
      ),
      focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: ThemeColors.border.secondary,
          width: _borderSideWidth,
        ),
      ),
      focusedErrorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: ThemeColors.text.tertiary,
          width: _borderSideWidth,
        ),
      ),
      errorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: this.widget.errorBorderColor ?? ThemeColors.text.tertiary,
          width: _borderSideWidth,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  TextInputType _getKeyboardType() {
    switch (this.widget.textFieldType) {
      case TextFieldType.Email:
        return TextInputType.emailAddress;
      default:
        return TextInputType.text;
    }
  }

  Widget _getSuffixIcon() {
    switch (this.widget.textFieldType) {
      case TextFieldType.Picker:
        return Icon(Icons.unfold_more);
      case TextFieldType.Password:
        return IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye),
          color: _shouldObscureText ? ThemeColors.icon.secondaryLight : ThemeColors.icon.secondary,
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _shouldObscureText = !_shouldObscureText;
            });
          },
        );
      case TextFieldType.Text:
        return this.widget.suffixIcon != null ? this.widget.suffixIcon : null;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }

  bool _shouldTextBeObscured() {
    if (widget.textFieldType == TextFieldType.Password) {
      return _shouldObscureText;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

And when you want to use it for Date picking just call it like this:

```
  TextFieldWidget(
    focusNode: _dateFocusNode,
    controller: _dateTextController,
    textFieldType: TextFieldType.Picker,
    hintText: 'Date of birth',
    onTap: () {
      if (FocusScope.of(context).hasFocus) {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
      }
      // Call code that opens date picker here
    },
  ),
```

Keep in mind this `TextField` provides more options than what you need right now, but if you plan on having error handling, different UI colours for those cases, different UI for password, email and other input this will be of great help.